# How to remove data saved in model class after calling delete button Api?

Tags: ios, swift

Here in my wishlist page I am having delete button after clicking I am making api to call to remove item in server but after removing it was success in server but in table view I am unable to remove it can anyone help me how to remove this and here data I am passing from model class ?

Here is my code

```
func deleteButtonAction(button: UIButton){
        let buttonPosition = button.convert(CGPoint(), to: tableDetails)
        let index = tableDetails.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)
        let obj = wishListModel[(index?.row)!]
        let deleteURL = "http://magento.selldesk.io/index.php/rest/V1/wishlist/delete/\(obj.wishlistItemId!)?customer_id=\(self.customerId!)"
        self.deleteWishListItemsDownloadJsonWithURl(deleteApi: deleteURL)
    }
func deleteWishListItemsDownloadJsonWithURl(deleteApi: String){
        let url = URL(string: deleteApi)
        var request = URLRequest(url: url! as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "DELETE"

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil { print(error!); return }
            do {
                if let jsonObj = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8) {
                    print(jsonObj)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                       self.tableDetails.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: Remove items from wishListModel array and reload table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove specific index, You have call `wishListModel.removeAtIndex(index)` 
 else if you want to remove all objects from wishListModel, use `wishListModel.removeAll(`) in success response from server.

P.S Make sure to remove object before calling `self.tableDetails.reloadData()`

Comment: but images not removing properly

Comment: means the same image will be there with content different

Comment: i'm not sure what are you asking?

Comment: name and price was removing but image has not been removed from a selected index

Comment: Can you update your question with cellForRow()'s code?

Comment: got it bro I had placed local server images in cell for row at indexpath forgot to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

If your api remove specific item then you need to remove index from your model and never forget to reload data after remove.

```
wishListModel.removeAtIndex(index_number)
self.tableDetails.reloadData()
```

but if your api delete all item from your server side then you need to do this.

```
wishListModel.removeAll()
```

after that never forget to reload data in tableview :)

```
self.tableDetails.reloadData()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made some change in your code, you can try this.

```
func deleteButtonAction(button: UIButton){
        let buttonPosition = button.convert(CGPoint(), to: tableDetails)
        let index = tableDetails.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)
        let obj = wishListModel[(index?.row)!]
        let deleteURL = "http://magento.selldesk.io/index.php/rest/V1/wishlist/delete/\(obj.wishlistItemId!)?customer_id=\(self.customerId!)"
        self.deleteWishListItemsDownloadJsonWithURl(deleteApi: deleteURL, atIndex:index)
    }
func deleteWishListItemsDownloadJsonWithURl(deleteApi: String, atIndex:IndexPath){
        let url = URL(string: deleteApi)
        var request = URLRequest(url: url! as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "DELETE"

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil { print(error!); return }
            do {
                if let jsonObj = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8) {
                    print(jsonObj)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                       wishListModel.removeAtIndex(atIndex.row)
                       self.tableDetails.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: here data is removing with my code and ur code also but here image was not changing